# Unknown property 'SetValue.Id'

Tags: visualforce, controller, set

While i'm displaying set data into vf page it's showing the error

vf code :--

```
<apex:page controller="Soql_Ct">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Soql_Example" >

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
                    <apex:column value="{!a.Id}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
         </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

apex code:--

```
public class Soql_Ct {
    public Set<Account> accounts {set;get;}
    public List<Account> myList {set;get;}
    public Soql_Ct(){
        myList=[select Id,Name,Phone,Industry,Rating,Ownership from Account];
        accounts=new Set<Account>();
        accounts.addAll(myList);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried iterating it through `myList` instead of `accounts`.?

Answer (score 0):

> I have just made a simple change. Try out with this.Set will only include unique values.Suppose your account with 2 different id but same names. This will only take one value. Or just use the same myList to return

```
public class Soql_Ct {
public list<Account> accounts {set;get;}
public List<Account> myList {set;get;}
public Soql_Ct (){
    myList=[select Id,Name,Phone,Industry,Rating,Ownership from Account];
    accounts=new list<Account>();
    accounts.addAll(myList);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By default when iterating through `Set<SObject>` on visualforce page using any iterator, it returns as a String and not of Object type. In your case, `a` is a string type and not sobject. When you try to access the `a.id` it gives you an error.

Declare `accounts` as a `List<Account>` else use `myList` in your Visualforce page.